# Mostrar frecuencia cardíaca con sensor de pulso y microcontrolador Particle Photon

Tags: c++

La intención de este proyecto, es mostrar la frecuencia cardíaca mediante un sensor de pulso (es el que tiene un corazón grabado en el lector).

El microcontrolador que estoy usando es un Photon de Particle.

El problema que tengo es que de todos los ejemplos en Internet que he usado, no me arrojan los resultados esperados.

No se si el problema radica en que esos ejemplos son echos con otros tipos de medida propios del pais, pero se supone que la frecuencia normal de una persona es entre 60 y 100 pulsasiones por minuto, sin embargo cuando lo pruebo el resultado es: 8.5 ppm (osea casi me mori), o 250 ppm (estoy apunto del infarto).

El otro problema que creo podria ser, es que esos ejemplos son para la placa Arduino y creo que hay funciones que no corren en Photon.

Agradecere mucho si alguien me podria orientar para solucionar este problema. El codigo que mas se acerco es este.

```
/* inicia codigo */

int UpperThreshold = 518;
int LowerThreshold = 490;
    int reading = 0;
    float BPM = 0.0;
    bool IgnoreReading = false;
    bool FirstPulseDetected = false;
    unsigned long FirstPulseTime = 0;
    unsigned long SecondPulseTime = 0;
    unsigned long PulseInterval = 0;

    void setup(){
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop(){

      reading = analogRead(0); 
      if(reading > UpperThreshold && IgnoreReading == false){
        if(FirstPulseDetected == false){
          FirstPulseTime = millis();
          FirstPulseDetected = true;
        }
        else{
          SecondPulseTime = millis();
          PulseInterval = SecondPulseTime - FirstPulseTime;
          FirstPulseTime = SecondPulseTime;
        }
        IgnoreReading = true;
      }
      if(reading < LowerThreshold){
        IgnoreReading = false;
      }  

      BPM = (1.0/PulseInterval) * 60.0 * 1000;
       // uncomment these lines in case you want to view the various values in the console.....
      /*Serial.print(reading);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(PulseInterval);
      Serial.print("\t");*/
      Serial.print(BPM);
      Serial.println(" BPM");
      Serial.flush();
    }

/* Fin codigo */
```

Se que es un numero u operacion pero no le hayo, cabe mencionar que en el video del ejemplo si da una frecuencia normal de 65 ppm, no se que es lo que este pasando !!!

Muchas gracais a todos por tomarse el tiempo

Comment: Sin dar un diagnóstico o algo parecido, esto depende mucho del sensor que uses. El código es relativamente sencillo, pero la forma en la que el sensor lidie con el ruido o la forma en la que interprete las diferentes ondas en una pulsación cardíaca (onda P, onda Q, etc) afectará los datos con los que trabaja el código. ¿Tienes forma de probar con otro sensor?

Comment: Hola, por el momento no, pero si estoy planeando comprar otro sensor, la cuestion es que ese sensor se adapta bastante bien a mi necesidad, sin embargo como lo comentaba, en los ejemplos que he probado son el mismo hardware, pero los resultados distintos, muchas gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos posibles explicaciones para tu error:

1. El sensor funciona correctamente, por lo que estás muerto y teniendo un infarto simultáneamente.
2. El código tiene un problema:

   1. Es incorrecto.
   2. Es correcto pero no tiene en cuenta particularidades del hardware.

Aunque la opción más interesante a nivel teológico, biológico, médico y espiritual sea el punto 1, mi apuesta está sobre el 2.2.

---

Tu código sólo registra dos lecturas y basa sus cálculos en ellas, si esas lecturas se hacen en un momento en que el sensor está descalibrado o mientras te colocas el sensor los resultados serán inconsistentes y heterogéneos ¡tal y como describes!

Para solucionar el problema evita esas situaciones o modifica tu código para que las maneje de manera adecuada. Como esta es una página sobre programación te haré una propuesta de código:

#### [KISS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS): usa listas.

Si realmente quieres almacenar sólo dos lecturas, evita la lógica basada en booleanos y pasa a lógica basada en datos:

```
std::list<unsigned long> lecturas;

void loop()
{
    const auto lectura = analogRead(0);
    if (lectura >= LowerThreshold && lectura <= UpperThreshold)
    {
        lecturas.push_front(lectura);
        while (lecturas.size() != 2)
            lecturas.pop_back();
    }

    auto BPM = (1ul / (lecturas.front() - lecturas.back())) * 60.0 * 1000;
}
```

Comment: Esta explicación está buena y la sugerencia puede funcionar. (A menos que la respuesta sea la opción 1 y el OP sea un zombie)

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una [guía](https://www.instructables.com/id/Particle-Photon-Pulse-Sensor/) sobre cómo usar el sensor en el Photon programable que estás usando.

Esencialmente, sugieren este código

```
#include "PulseSensor_Spark/SparkIntervalTimer.h"
void interruptSetup(void);
void serialOutput();
void serialOutputWhenBeatHappens();
void sendDataToSerial(char symbol, int data );
void ledFadeToBeat();
void arduinoSerialMonitorVisual(char symbol, int data );

extern int pulsePin;
extern int blinkPin;
extern volatile int BPM;;
extern volatile int Signal;;
extern volatile int IBI;
extern volatile boolean Pulse;
extern volatile boolean QS;
const int numReadings = 10;
int readings[numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
int readIndex = 0;              // the index of the current reading
int total = 0;                  // the running total
int average = 0; 
int bpmm;
extern int fadePin;
extern int fadeRate;

void setup(){

    Spark.variable("getpos", &bpmm, INT);
    pinMode(blinkPin,OUTPUT);         // pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
    pinMode(fadePin,OUTPUT);          // pin that will fade to your heartbeat!
    Serial.begin(115200);             // we agree to talk fast!
    interruptSetup();                 // sets up to read Pulse Sensor signal every 2mS
    for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++) {
    readings[thisReading] = 0;
  }
}

void loop(){
     // subtract the last reading:
  total = total - readings[readIndex];
  // read from the sensor:
  readings[readIndex] = BPM;
  // add the reading to the total:
  total = total + readings[readIndex];
  // advance to the next position in the array:
  readIndex = readIndex + 1;

  // if we're at the end of the array...
  if (readIndex >= numReadings) {
    // ...wrap around to the beginning:
    readIndex = 0;
  }

  // calculate the average:
  average = total / numReadings;
  // send it to the computer as ASCII digits
    bpmm = average;
}
```

Por lo que se ve, parece que da valores más cercanos a la realidad. Creo que el detalle está en cómo calcula el valor y cómo se configura el `serial.begin`